# How can I find corresponding balanced parentheses?

Tags: motion, sexp, delimiters

I have this LaTeX code:

```
\caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet: foo), bar), baz) and qux) consectetuer adipiscing elit.}
```

I want to put a marker immediately before the first `{` and one immediately after its corresponding `}`.

`forward-list` is my usual choice in order to find balanced parentheses, but in this case it is not suitable because it moves cursor immediately after the first `)` (as its standard behaviour).

How can I do this?

```
;; my standard way
(while (re-search-forward "\\\\\\<caption\\>" nil t)
  (setq pos1 (point-marker))
  (set-marker-insertion-type pos1 t)
  (forward-list)
  (setq pos2 (point-marker))
  (set-marker-insertion-type pos2 t)
  (save-excursion
    (save-restriction
      (narrow-to-region pos1 pos2)
      (goto-char (point-min))
      ;; do something
      )))
```

**Updates**

I have found an answer here:

[Strict parenthesis matching](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/NavigatingParentheses)

Function `forward-pexp` does the trick.

Comment: `(search-forward "}")` perhaps?

Comment: @NickD The problem with `(search-forward "}")` is that `\caption{...}` can contain many other `{ }` as in `\ref{ }` or `\cite{ }` or in math expression like `^{-1}` and so on.

Comment: `(forward-sexp)` does not work in this case, but `(sp-forward-sexp)` from the `smartparens` package works.

Answer (score -1):

Use `forward-sexp`, bound to `C-M-f`.

See these nodes of the Emacs and Elisp manuals:

- [Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Expressions.html)
- [List Motion](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/List-Motion.html)

Comment: In my experiments, that did not work on the OP's example.

Comment: You're right, with that text. Sounds like a bug, to me. The delimiter paired with `{` should be `}`, not `)`, no?

Comment: @Drew Please, could you be more clear abount "bound to `C-M-f`"?

Comment: @Drew - I thought so, but maybe I'm missing something. Part of the problem I think is the unbalanced parens in the OP's example, e.g. in cc-mode, `C-M-f` goes from `{` to `}` but only if the other paren-like things in-between balance.

Comment: @NickD: Yeah, I can see an argument for that as the proper behavior. But it doesn't sound correct to me, in a mode such as LaTeX. I'd think that it should just look for a closing `}`.

Comment: @NickD: FYI, I just filed bug #[41442](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=41442) for this.

Comment: @OnnerIrotsab: `forward-sexp` is bound to the key sequence `C-M-f` in LaTeX mode, no? By that, I mean that if you press `Control` and `Meta` and `f`, that invokes command `forward-sexp`.

Comment: @Drew - thanks!